# <true> but was: <false> - i don't know how to solve it

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to run a test for a method but i always get the same error.

This is my test class:

```
private Car car;

@Autowired
protected CarService carService;

@Mock
private CarRepository carRepository;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    car = new Car();
    car.setId(4L);
    car.setName("test1");
    car.setUrlCar("https://carconfigurator.ferrari.com/assets/cars/portofinom/packages/default/car-ferrari-portofino-m_splash.jpg");
    car.setColor("red");
    carRepository.save(car);
    }

@Test
void getCarById() throws Exception {
    Car res = this.carService.getCarById(4L);
    Assertions.assertTrue(res != null);
}
```

The CarService class is:

```
@Autowired
private carRepository carRepository;

public Iterable<Car> getAllCars(){
    return carRepository.findAll();
}
public Car getCarById(Long id){
    return carRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

The trace is:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
```

The trace points to the line `Assertions.assertTrue(res != null);` and i don't know how to solve the error. If u could help me please.

Comment: Well, you've got a null reference where you expect a reference to a Car.  Which line of code that you wrote can return null instead of a reference to a Car?

Comment: The first step is to make sure you understand the message. The second step is to make an attempt to diagnose the cause. The third step is to share your attempt with us, and explain specifically what you found confusing or unexpected, i.e., specifically what prevented you from fixing it yourself. My guess is that it has something to do with the contents of either `CarRepository.findById` or `CarRepository.save`; but we can only help with code that we can see. It's also unclear to me what you expect the `.orElse(null)` part to accomplish here. Under what conditions would it *change* the result?

Answer (score 2):

You are *mocking* the `CarRepository` but not specifying any behavior for it, so when the service calls it, the mock returns null. You need to say something like

```
when(carRepository.findOne(4L)).thenReturn(car)
```

Additionally, you should avoid `assertTrue` unless you mean to say "this object is true". Instead, you should use more meaningful assertions such as `assertNotNull`.

(You can also eliminate the unnecessary dependency on Spring; just create your `CarRepository` mock and say `new CarService(mockCarRepository)`.)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to assert that res is not null to avoid a NullPointerException; the better way is to write code that doesn't cause a NullPointerException. Read on google about NPEs, there are **millions** of posts on it. So get rid of `Assertions.assertTrue(res != null);` and use something like a try/catch (read on google) or just

```
if (res==null){/*code here*/}
else {/*your normal code*/}
```

Comment: Right. It's test code.  It's perfectly reasonable, indeed laudable, for test code to assert that a particular result must not be null.

Comment: i'll add it thank u! but i want the test to be a success, not to get a null in return. So might i think that the car i created is not being saved correctly?

Comment: As observed above, your problem likely lives in getCarById().  Whether it's the finding part, or the original saving part, I can't say at a casual glance.

Comment: @riley, that may be. Another cause of npe's is you may have run the code before you create the car. Code will run in sequence, so a car should be made before you try to access it.